# How does intro.js works?

Tags: javascript, html, css, intro.js

I have an on boarding tour in at [my.bonify.de](https://my.bonify.de). It offers a similar experience to [introjs](http://introjs.com/).

We implemented this in a very ugly way using a cutout div with a very large box-shadow. We would like to improve upon this and use an overlay like introjs since it seems to have much better performance than our dirty hack.

Having read **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)**, I do not understand how introjs works since the element to be highlighted should definitely be in a lower stacking context.

I have tried replicating the behaviour with our own onboarding but I can not get the element in the page to rise above the overlay.

I would like to know how introjs achieves this, I thought that [this block of code](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/intro.js#L1060) was the secret but when I put a debugger the class is not added.

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried so that it is easier to find out where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy, you just put a relative element with higher z-index on top of a fixed element. Sample classes:

```
.fixed-elem {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.relative-elem {
  position:relative;
  z-index:10;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/7ergcfvq/1/

Comment: I figured out my mistake. There was a parent with a defined z-index that was causing the issue, the jsfiddle was useful to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look at demo step 1 of intro.js, the `<h1>Intro.js</h1>` element has `.introjs-relativePosition` and `.introjs-showElement`, so it got `position:relative` and `z-index:9999999!important`.

And the `<div class="intros-overlay">`'s z-index `999999`, smaller than `<h1>` & `<div class="introjs-helperLayer">`